# Parse JSON object as Interface in Dart

Tags: json, interface, dart

I have an interface Employee and Department. I'm loading JSON from server that I need to "parse" to object that implements those interfaces. Is there a way how to achieve this automatically since all types in interface and JSON object are base types (String, number, list, map)?

```
// Abstract classes represents interfaces
abstract class Employee {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
}

abstract class Department {
  String name;
  List<Employee> employees;
}

// JSON
{
  "name": "Development",
  "employees":
  [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
  ]
}
```

I want to parse it like this

```
main() {
  ...
  Department department = someMethodToParse(jsonFromServer);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few packages that deal with JSON de/serialization

- http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/serialization/0.9.1+1/index.html#serialization/serialization (serialization package)
- [Can I automatically serialize a Dart object to send over a Web Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423318) (package exportable)
- [Convert JS object into Dart classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021350) (manual)
- [How to convert an object containing DateTime fields to JSON in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537114) (handling DateDime)
- [Add JSON serializer to every model class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024298)